# Java implements webbrowser: does this save to browser cache, and can you serve content directly?

Tags: java, browser, swt, implements, jxbrowser

Still trying to decide which application will suit : current options JxBrowser vs SWT widget.

Java application implements a webbrowser control like [JxBrowser](http://www.teamdev.com/downloads/jxbrowser/docs/JxBrowser-PGuide.html) or [SWT browser control](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-browser-widget/browser.html). Both of these provide options to pass info from java to javascript.

Now I need to know: Is it possible not to save the html/css/javascript file into the cache? Is it possible to have java serve the content as  input (looks like this is possible with SWT, unsure of JxBrowser).

Essentially I don't want to have temporary files, either in the cache or in temp folder, and I want to feed the information from an input stream.

Or do you have to roll/embed your own browser to avoid having all saved to cache?

Perhaps for clarity: I am asking if these two programs offer defined methods when implementing their own browser from within java, to not cache, and if you can stream input directly to serve the html / css/ javascript content.

I understand the no-cache methods in a webbrowser, here I am simply asking whether embedding the browser behaves in the same way. The documentation does not seem very specific about this issue, but perhaps I need to look more.

On further looking it looks like it saves files to cache. Secondly, methods like clearing the cache are so non-specific that if you call clear cache function you happen to have to empty the clients entire cache. Argh....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to render HTML from memory by SWT `Browser` widget. I'm not sure how is it with caching those pages (it may depend on used browser), but it seems reasonable not cache those pages.

See [SWT Browser snippets](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/#browser) for additional info about rendering HTML from memory.